# Views pending Promotion list

Tags: view

I need to create a view that will show list of employees that have spent two years at an organisation and are pending for Confirmation or Promotion.
My challenge is I can filter by date but I want to be able to filter by number of days that he has been employed, that way the list is auto generated.
I am using pop Calendar as the date picker.
Please help